# During the publishing of a .Net web application, what's the best way to make the application unavailable to users?

Tags: asp.net

When you publish a .Net application - what's the easiest way to put something up for users that says 'this application is currently being upgraded, please try later'

Answer (score 4):

If you create a file in the folder called `app_offline.htm`, your application will serve that to users instead of the application. ScottGu has a great blog post on it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx).

I tend to add one of these to every project but call it `app_online.htm`, then when I need to make changes I can just rename the file instead of having to create one from scratch.

Comment: How (very interesting)? Where is this documented?

Comment: @Patrick Strangely I can't find any particular MSDN page that describes this behaviour, though it's been around for a good long while now. It's mentioned in a walkthrough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: @PhilPursglove: I did not know that one, pretty nifty. (Does this work on Mono as well?)

Comment: @Patrick I thought *everyone* knew about it, I was a bit surprised to see this question! Mono: don't know for certain but the comments in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626764/how-to-refresh-mono-asp-net-page-without-restarting-the-web-server suggest it doesn't work for Mono...

Comment: @PhilPursglove: I guess I'm in the ~everyone group in that case. Thanks for the Mono find as well. :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew (think) that file gets created automatically when you publish - and is then removed. Couldn't remember what it was called though.

Comment: @Patrick No offence intended, this feature's been in the product since ASP.NET 2.0 and I have a tendency to assume that everyone's been doing ASP.NET as long as me and seen all these features get added...

Comment: @Mike I didn't know the Publish feature creates it for you while it's working :-)